# Sort an Array comparing another array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 array of which one is for order and another where the real value has to be sorted. How can I sort the array by comparing array? Any Idea will be really helpful. Thank You.

Order Array:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [code] => subscription_bundles
        [id_sequency] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [code] => pre_order
        [id_sequency] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [code] => voucher
        [id_sequency] => 3
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [code] => ppv
        [id_sequency] => 4
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [code] => ppv_bundle
        [id_sequency] => 5
    )
)
```

And To Sort Array:

```
Array(
[monetization] => Array
    (
        [ppv] => Pay Per View
        [ppv_bundle] => Pay-Per-View Bundle
        [subscription_bundles] => Subscription
        [voucher] => Voucher
    )
```

Comment: You missed `pre_order`?

Comment: @vivek_23 I didnt missed that. The data in sort_array is dynamic

Comment: @SougataBose  first_array(code) = second_array['monetization][key]

Comment: @SougataBose - this question isn't a duplicate of your linked one..

Comment: Not fully but the logic would be almost same. Though reopened the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `uksort` in combination with `array_combine` to create a key-order mapping from the order array.

```
// create order mapping
$map = array_combine(
    array_column($order, 'code'),
    array_column($order, 'id_sequency')
);

// sort the data
uksort($data, function ($a, $b) use ($map) {
    return $map[$a] - $map[$b];
});
```

Comment: I didn't get what you did and its not working. And FYI first_array(code) = second_array['monetization][key]

Comment: come on - show some effort.. replace `$data` with `$second_array['monetization']`

Comment: obviously, I did that. Still i didn't got